# Install domain with oracle ADF on Windows, stuck at the schema configuration window

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c

I am currently learning how to use Oracle ADF. I am trying to deploy the .ear generated by JDeveloper 12c to A WebLogic server. So far, my understanding is that I need to create a "domain", and that this domain must include the Oracle ADF Runtime. So I started the config.cmd util that allow me to create a new domain.

Alas, I am stuck at the following screen.

[image: confusing screen]

(from their documentation)

I have *no idea* what that means. The Oracle documentation is terribly unclear and so I can't find why this is needed, and what exactly "RCU Data" is supposed to be.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I need to do for this screen?

Answer (score 1):

That is the domain creation screen for a Fusion Middleware installation like SOA Suite. This kind of domain requires a database and the specific schemas to support the desired products in the  domain. These are created with the  Repository Creation Utility (RCU). You would supply the schema owner name here and the UI will find the schemas and configure the domain for you. However, this is **not** what **you** need.

Easiest thing to do is to go into JDeveloper and simply choose Start Server from the run menu and give it a password of your choosing and let JDeveloper create the Integrated WLS domain for you and then you can deploy and run to that domain from JDev with a simple Run command. However, when you shut down JDev, it shuts down the Domain. If you want a standalone domain then you should go to "wlsserverhome"/oracle_common/common/bin/config.cmd, choose "Oracle JRF - 12.xxx" from the list and then take the rest of the defaults.

This installs the ADF runtime (Java Runtime Framework) and then you start the domain from the /startWeblogic.cmd and you should be all set. Note - you will want to create an Application server connection from within JDev to this server once you start it so that you can deploy directly to it from JDev - else use JDev to create your ear file and deploy to WLS via console or wlst script. hth.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I may go the JDevelopper route if all else fail. That said, I would really prefer having some sort of stand-alone staging server to run my integration tests. Thing is, I did only select Oracle JRF 12.1.3 from the list, and only that. It still lead me to this screen. Could it be that this version of Oracle JRF now require a database to store some data?

Comment: that's odd. I tested this myself on WLS 12.1.3 install and it did not ask for the RCU. What version wls  are you using? also, you might try download and install the Jdev studio version which, once installed, will have WLS as well and you could try that domain config. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html

Comment: There are essentially 2 versions of wls/jdev to download: jdev studio w/o FMW and with FMW. If you downloaded the FMW version, then yes it will ask for RCU. But, even then, you can create a "Standalone" domain that will use derbydb and no RCU needed. You would then need to add the ADF runtime, here: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#SOAQS251 (then, search for: 2.5.2 Configuring a Standalone Domain). But, this is less desirable because it will start SOA Suite and be much longer to startup.

Comment: If getting started with ADF, you might find my aggregation site helpful:https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-links and this book is *highly* recommended: Oracle JDeveloper 11g Handbook: A Guide to Fusion Web Development
http://www.amazon.com/Oracle-JDeveloper-11g-Handbook-Development/dp/0071602380/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301065987&sr=8-1

Comment: I'll try reinstalling everything. Maybe I just did something wrong the first time. In my desperation I may have downloaded the latest 12.2.1 version and trashed something.

Comment: I reinstalled JDeveloper, the new version 12.2.1 has a "Restricted JRF" option that does not require a database connection. That'll do. :) Thank you for your input.